# Python - Regular Expression count "he" and "she"

Tags: python

I'm working on a regular expression that finds **he or she** that is surrounded by white space, so not finding he in other words (standalone). It is searching through a book.

I have tried the '+' 'and'

```
def q9():
pattern = r'\s(he)\s'
return re.compile(pattern)
```

This returns 1371 values when it should be 2000 *This part doesn't really apply to you unless you know the book*

Comment: Your regex will find only `'he'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
re.compile(r'\bs?he\b', re.I)
```

`re.I` do case-insentitive matching, `\b` is for word boundary, `s?he` means `s` is optional and `he` should always be matched. Equavalent way to write this is `r'\b(she|he)\b'` if you want to be more readable.